# voyager - (Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException] There are no commands defined in the "voyager" namespace)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So I am trying to install Voyager for my laravel, but when I insert

> php artisan voyager:install

I am getting this error message:

> (Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException] There
>   are no commands defined in the "voyager" namespace)

Here is my PhP and Laravel version:

> Laravel Framework version 5.3.16
>
> λ php -v PHP 7.0.13 (cli) (built: Nov 8 2016 13:45:28) ( ZTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright
>   (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

And my package service providers:

/*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */

```
TCG\Voyager\VoyagerServiceProvider::class,
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
```

So what is the problem? why am I getting this error message

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you didn't install it. Comment out or remove service providers from the list and run these commands:

```
composer require tcg/voyager
composer dumpauto
```

According to [the docs](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager), next step will be adding a service provider to the `config/app.php`:

```
TCG\Voyager\VoyagerServiceProvider::class,
```

And only then run `php artisan voyager:install` command.

Comment: But why if I didn't install it, it stI'll appears in composer.json. I will give it a go and see if that helps

Comment: @Przemek how did you install it? What error message did you see? Did you see a message about published commands or something like this?

Comment: I installed it using composer require just as you mentioned above. Didn't see any error messages while installing. After I have added that package and tried to run php artisan voyager:install and I've got that error message which is in the question

Comment: your solution didn't help, still getting same error message

Comment: Same problem here and the advice (above, which is the same as on the repo) doesn't work.

Comment: @WayneSmallman if you will comment this out as I said in my answer and if you don't use the class anywhere you'll not get the error message. It's impossible. So guys who still get the error, read the answer carefully and do things step by step. I bet you just didn't remove service provider or you're trying to use it somewhere in your app. So, just double check everything and read the answer carefully.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, I've opened an issue on the repo, and I'm in discussion with someone who's investigating, because these instructions do not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan config:clear
```

solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully executed the command line:

> composer require tcg/voyager

You must have the line  "tcg/voyager": "^1.2" in the require section of your composer.json file, in this case the command line "composer dumpautoload" will automatically perform all the packages discovery for you. Otherwise do the following :

add the line of code: TCG\Voyager\VoyagerServiceProvider::class to the file "config/app.php". Then run the following command line :

> composer dumpautoload